# How to automate reply in outlook via Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying my luck to have a program wherein you could reply to selected email in outlook using Excel VBA. Unfortunately, I can't find any working code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplyMSG()
  Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
  Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient
  Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection

  Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
  Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection

  For Each olItem In myOlSel
  Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
  Set olRecip = olReply.Recipients.Add("Email Address Here") ' Recipient Address
    olRecip.Type = olCC
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Hello, Thank you. " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
    olReply.Display

    'olReply.Send
  Next olItem
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use this code but error 438 object doesn't support this property or method keeps on coming out. Hoping to get help with this automation.

Comment: If you are writing in Excel VBA, then the term `Application` applies to Excel. Excel Application doesn't have `ActiveExplorer` property. You should hook back to your Outlook Application which i do not see in the code supplied, like `Set myOlExp = myOutlookApp.ActiveExplorer`

Comment: What you mean on this? The code already set it to Outlook app in here `Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing in Excel VBA, then the term Application applies to Excel. Excel Application doesn't have ActiveExplorer property. You should hook back to your Outlook Application which i do not see in the code supplied, like Set `myOlExp = refToOutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer`

Look at what you have shown above:

`Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer`

This means `Set myOlExp = Excel.Application.ActiveExplorer`, and the thing is that Excel Application has no Explorer Object.

So you need: `Set myOlExp = refToOutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer`

You need to explicitly state that you wish to assign a variable to the property of the Outlook Application - which at this stage I am going to assume that you have created a reference somewhere else earlie in your module.

If not, then you will need to do so with:

```
Dim refToOutlookApplication As Object    'Outlook.Application
Set refToOutlookApplication = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```